# Delete Device using rest API of Azure device provisioning service?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

What is the format of the url needed to delete an already registered device in azure IoT hub using device provisioning service...

I read this article but it throws me 404

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/deletedeviceregistrationstate/deletedeviceregistrationstate

In the request header I added If-Match tag but do I need to add Authorization tag with the SaS token and if I need the SaS token will be the one which I used for registering device using Device Provisioning Service

Answer (score 0):

> if I need the SaS token will be the one which I used for registering
> device using Device Provisioning Service

There are some steps that you need to follow to generate the `access_token` that will be used in the `Authorization` header of the request.

Prerequisites:

- Install [Python 2.7+](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
- Install [Azure CLI 2.0+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)
- Login to CLI

Below are the steps:

> Login with Azure CLI

`az login`

> Set Active Subscription

`az account set --subscription "your subscription name or id"`

> Create Service Principal

`az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "your service principal name. Can be like 'jongpostman7'"`

The output of above command will be something like below image.
[image]

Copy this output to a temp location, you will need the values in a minute.

Coming to the Postman request now. You need to first call the `AAD Token request` whose response will provide you with the `access_token`. This access token you can use in the DPS delete device request. The AAD request will be like below:-

POST `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token`
Refer image below for the request body.

[image]

`grant_type` is `client_credentials`
`client_id` is the `appId` received in above command output
`client_secret` is the `password` received in above command output
`tenant_id` is the `tenant` received in above command output
`resource` is `https://management.azure.com/`

The response of above request will be like below:-
[image]

Now, you have the `access_token` that can be used in the DPS delete device REST API.
The Authorization header be like below:

`Authorization`: `Bearer <access_token_received_above>`

Reference link [here](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/).

Comment: hi, thanks but i need to do it like in this article, the sas token for deleting device is like this:https://github.com/TP73/azure-docs/blob/088e1afa3acc84b26fd4f9038afc4708bece5644/articles/iot-dps/how-to-control-access.md

Comment: @Liverpool If you want to use the REST api for any of the Azure service, there is no other way than generating the access token as per the answer above. Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/. Regarding the SaS token i.e. symmetric key it is not part of the  Delete api as per the Azure doc. Can you try the above procedure?