# Delete (deprovision) device in azure iot hub using device client and device provisioning service using HTTP DELETE

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

What causes this problem of getting Unauthorized when trying to delete a device from azure IoT hub using the DPS:

[Documentation](https://github.com/TP73/azure-docs/blob/088e1afa3acc84b26fd4f9038afc4708bece5644/articles/iot-dps/how-to-control-access.md)

[Documentation for delete operation using DPS in azure iot hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/deletedeviceregistrationstate/deletedeviceregistrationstate#provisioningserviceerrordetails)

I tried deprovision device but also getting error 401 or 405. What is the format for the sas token which is used in the authorization header:

Code which generate the sas token:

```
public String buildSasToken1(String deviceId) throws SecurityProviderException {

        String keyValue = Utils.getKeyValue(deviceId, iotConfig.getSymmetricKey());
        Long expiry = getExpiry(iotConfig.getExpiry());
        try {
            String dpsUrl=iotConfig.getHubUrl1();
            String targetUri = URLEncoder.encode(dpsUrl.toLowerCase(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            String toSign = targetUri + "\n" + expiry;
            byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64Local(keyValue.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(signingKey);
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            
            String signature = URLEncoder.encode(Base64.encodeBase64StringLocal(rawHmac), "UTF-8");
            String token = String.format(iotConfig.getTokenFormat(), targetUri, signature, expiry)+"&skn=provisioningserviceowner";
            log.info("TOKEN "+token);
            return token;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I attach pictures which are showing the request in PostMan:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you delete the device in the web portal if you use the same user that you use in Postman?

Comment: I didn't try becouse i need to do it with http cal from java spring app and i didnt know why i am getting 401, if the sas token is wrong what is the format and how is build.I didnt find any info in the net...

Comment: @Liverpool did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237640/delete-device-using-rest-api-of-azure-device-provisioning-service/64238842#64238842